# How do I enable the Vim folding commands?

Tags: python, vim, folding

Vim 8. I have installed the SimpylFold plugin for Python folding. It is folding the code correctly, but these commands don't work in Normal mode:

```
:zo
:zc
:zR
```

I get the message "Not an editor command".

If I check `:set foldmethod?` it shows `expr`.  What am I missing?

Comment: No colon, these are normal-mode shortcuts.  The colon puts you into Ex-mode.

Comment: Did you set the fold method to syntax? 
       set foldmethod=syntax

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that these shortcuts are entered directly in Normal mode and *not* into the command line. So just `zo`, `zc`, `zR`. Similar to `x` for deleting a character, `u` for undo, etc.